How do I do a 'terms' JSON facet query on a Solr DateRangeField
I have a Solr index with one of the fields being a solr.DateRangeField, object_production_year_range_dt.
I have added some custom field definitions to my schema:
<fieldType class="solr.DateRangeField" indexed="true" name="range_date" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="*_range_dt" required="false" stored="true" type="range_date"/>

Indexed documents contain object_production_year_range_dt fields with values like [2017-01-01 TO *] and [1997-01-01 TO 2003-01-01].
These fields work great for doing queries with a specific year, and Solr will return all documents where the date falls within the range.
I also have a succesful range json facet query, which looks like:
"object_production_year_range": {
    "type": "range",
    "field": "object_production_year_range_dt",
    "start": "NOW-75YEAR/YEAR",
    "end": "NOW",
    "gap": "+1YEAR",
    "mincount" : 1,
    "limit": 50,
}

This will return the count per year.
However, I now want to return the counts of the date ranges as they have been indexed. I cannot get this to work. The buckets remain empty.
I have tried to reduce the facet query to the bare minimum,
"production_year": {
    "type": "terms",
    "field": "object_production_year_range_dt",
    "mincount": 1
}

but the buckets remain empty:
"production_year": {
    "buckets": [
    ]
},

I've gone over the documentation, trawled Stack Overflow, asked some LLMs, but haven't found a solution so far.

Further research leads me to believe it isn't possible, since the ranges aren't discrete values that can be bucketed.
For future readers: I have now solved the issue by adding the range as a explicit string value production_date_range_s on the ingestion side, which I can then use for the facet query.
